# How to run a saved update query in access from a python script?

Tags: python, ms-access

I am trying to automate a process at work so the user can simply run a python script instead of going into ms access to run each query and export tables individually.

The query is a saved update query and it needs to be running before the export of any tables.

I have the export working properly but I can not figure out how to get the query to run properly.

I found an answer that said,

> If the query is some other type of query (e.g., `SELECT` with
>   parameters, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, ...) then the Access `ODBC` driver
>   exposes them as Stored Procedures so you need to use the `ODBC {CALL...}` syntax, as in

```
import pyodbc
connStr = (
    r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    r"DBQ=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;"
    )
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
sql = """\
{CALL mySavedUpdateQueryInAccess}
"""

crsr = cnxn.execute(sql)
cnxn.commit()
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

but I keep getting the error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\servi\OneDrive\Documents\Haley\Licence_Management_Test\Mercator_Licence_Management.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       qry = con.execute(SQL_qry) pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in
>   UPDATE statement. (-3503) (SQLExecDirectW)')

```
import csv
import pyodbc

# constants
MDB = ("Z:\\pathway;")  
DRV='{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
PWD="password"

# connect to db
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={};PWD={}'.format(DRV,MDB,PWD))
cur = con.cursor()
filepath = ("C:\\pathway")    

#run query
SQL_qry = "UPDATE * CALL qry_Master_Licence_List;"               
qry = con.execute(SQL_qry)                         # executes command

print ("Querying results")

#get table info
SQL_tbl = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_Master_Licence_List;'
rows = cur.execute(SQL_tbl).fetchall()


cur.close()
con.close()

#export table as .csv

with open(filepath + 'Master_Licence_List.csv', 'w', newline='') as 
fou:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fou)
```

Comment: Please provide the SQL of the query you're trying to call. There are multiple functions and syntax features that aren't available when calling a query through an ODBC connection (common examples are the `Nz` function, UDFs, bang notation).

Comment: Hi Erik, the SQL of the query I'm trying to call is:                                    
UPDATE tbl_Master_Licence_List                                                             
INNER JOIN NovaRoc_All_Active                                                                   
ON tbl_Master_Licence_List.Licence_Number = NovaRoc_All_Active.[Right Number] SET tbl_Master_Licence_List.Holder = [NovaRoc_All_Active]![Holder Name], tbl_Master_Licence_List.Optioned_Owned = IIf([tbl_Master_Licence_List]![Holder] Like "########*","Owned","Optioned");

Comment: Start by replacing all those exclamation marks with dots. As said in my first comment, bang notation doesn't work when calling a query over ODBC.

Comment: I have taken the exclamation marks out of the sql and I am still having the same issue is there any way its a problem with the python script? I have looked everywhere and cannot determine if I am missing parameters in the update statement

Comment: You're using the top code, right, with `sql = "{CALL mySavedUpdateQueryInAccess}"`? This: `SQL_qry = "UPDATE * CALL qry_Master_Licence_List;" ` won't work, `UPDATE *` is nonsense and `CALL QueryName` needs to be surrounded by braces.

Comment: AH thank you! I got it to work